# Edit xlsx file without lost format and formulas with XLSX.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I need to edit a XLSX file in a nodejs application for create an order sheet. the file I need to edit have a specific format and some formulas. I try to use several libraries but the only one I found that able to read and write xlsx files is [XLSX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js/).

But when I try to read the xlsx file and write the same content in a file, I lost the format and all formulas on the new file. Please find hereunder the piece of code that I use :

```
var xl = require('../public/javascripts/xlsx'),
    fs = require('fs-extra'),
    inFile = 'conf/X-Pole_Order_Form.xlsx',
    outFile = "conf/tmp.xlsx";

fs.copy(inFile, outFile, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('Not enable to copy excel file');
    }
    fs.readFile(outFile, 'base64', function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('Problem by reading excel file');
        }
        var sheet = xl(content);
        fs.writeFile(outFile, sheet.base64, 'base64');
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea or other solution to propose ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [two year old blog pos](http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=24)t by the author of that library (emphasis mine):

> Right now XLSX.js supports reading data from multiple worksheets, the
>   names of the worksheets, the active worksheet, and file metadata. ***It
>   does not support the reading of formatting information***, macros,
>   charts, or anything else.

Reading through the [changelog for that file](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js/commits/master/xlsx.js) I don't see much was added that is format related. There is a [pull request from someone](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js/pull/26) that adds a little bit of formatting that you could try to implement but I don't think you're going to get full-blown Excel formatting from this library anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to find another solution.